# How to find annual interest percent in debentures

Tags: percentages

Find the annual interest percent on 17% debentures of the face value of Rupees 100 each and available at Rupees 85 each.

All I understand here investment 85 rupees. And income 17%

So it is $\frac {17}{85}$

I also searched online for steps but no where i found.

But all i want to know proper method to write steps as I am a school student.

Comment: No it is not $\frac {17}{85}$. That is not how percentages work at all. "$17\%$" literally means "seventeen per one hundred" or "seventeen out of each one hundred". "Per" means "out of" or "divided by", while "cent" comes from the Latin for "100". So $17\%$ itself is $\frac {17}{100}$, and $17\%$ of $85$ is $\left(\frac{17}{100}\right)85$. Unfortunately, I do not understand "17% debentures of the face value of Rupees 100 each and available at Rupees 85 each", so I do not know if $71\%$ of $85$ is actually the calculation you need to make.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair answer given is 20%. Please can you help now.